# C++ Dereferencing a Struct Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a question regarding C++ structs and pointers.

So let's say I define a struct called 'info'. This struct has a member called 'state'.

Now let's say I declare an instance of 'info' and I then I declare a pointer of 'info' type. If I only wanted to work with the pointer, how would I go about dereferencing the struct such that I could modify the value of 'state'?

For example:

```
info instance;
info * pointer = &instance;

//Want to change the value of 'state' to 23

*pointer.state = 23;

// or

*(pointer).state = 23;

// or

*(info.currentState) = 23;
```

Will either of these cases work?

Comment: ...have you tried any of these?

Comment: #03 !??? You are trying to dereference the type AND you are changing a different struct member.

Comment: A simple google search will reveal numerous tutorials and examples. I highly recommend you do that before posting questions like these. Also there are online C++ compilers and IDE to evaluate your answers. Go ahead and try that first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `(*pointer).state = 23;` but the preferred method is `pointer->state = 23;`

Basically, when you are referencing a public variable from a struct or class the notation is `object.item` or `pointerToObject->item`

The arrow notation automatically de-references the pointer for you.